# Cognos TM1 Insight - How to transport a screen between servers

Tags: cognos, cognos-tm1

I have erased a TM1 application on Server 1, and imported the project back from Server2 backup. However during this import it seems I've lost the screens designed in TM1 insight (with all grids, tabs, buttons, etc). Now what I see in Insight is basically the tabs as if it's opened in web browser, as a web application.

Therefore the current status: Server 1 with bare bone design, and server 2 has most up-to date design which needs to be imported on S1.

As it seems "Import" feature is not enough by itself, do I need to copy a particular folder to get the screens, or change a config during the export from S2? What did I miss?
How can I transport the existing screen designs from dev to test environment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by following those steps:

1. From Insight, open the application on Server 2
2. export the screen (via "Save As" option),
3. open the container file (with `.cdd` extension) with a file compression software (7zip, etc)
4. change the server connection settings written in the xml fine inside the container with the  new one you want to: (in this case, from `http://server2:9510/.../` to `http://server1:9510/.../`
5. replace modified xml with the original xml in `.cdd` file
6. open the file with Insight (double check if the server url is correctly set)
7. (save and) publish.